# How to calculate interval time between certain event types? - SQL

Tags: sql, database, time, google-bigquery, window-functions

I want to calculate the total interval time between all `event_type` A:

Sample Data (note: there can be multiple intervals to be summed together per `id`)

```
id    start_time         end_time          event_type
1     00:00:00.00000     00:00:00.04300    A
1     00:00:00.04300     00:00:00.08600    B
1     00:00:00.08600     00:00:00.12900    C
1     00:00:00.12900     00:00:00.13200    A
2     00:00:00.00000     00:00:00.05900    B
2     00:00:00.05900     00:00:00.06900    A
```

Calculation:

```
id = 1: 129 - 43 = 86 ms
id = 2: Only 1 A event_type so no interval = 0 ms
```

Desired Result:

```
id    interval_time
1     86
2     0
```

My Attempt:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   id
 , SUM(CASE
        WHEN event_type <> 'A'
          THEN TIME_DIFF(end_time, start_time, MILLISECOND)
        ELSE 0 
      END) OVER (PARTITION BY id)
FROM my_table
```

However, this doesn't account for cases where there are only 1 or 0 A `event_type`s for the `id`. So I'm looking for a better solution to calculate the interval times which are the cumulative sum of times between `event_type` A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT     
  id
, CASE 
     WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN activity_type = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
     OVER (PARTITION BY id) IN (0, 1)
        THEN 0
     ELSE SUM(CASE
        WHEN activity_type <> 'A'
          THEN TIME_DIFF(end_time, start_time, MILLISECOND)
        ELSE 0 
      END) OVER (PARTITION BY id)
  END
     AS interval_time
FROM my_table
```